# replacing all instances of a character in a string with '\0' doesn't work

Tags: arrays, c, loops, pointers, char

The file contains the string:

```
40,30,20,10            //newline at end
50,60,70,80
```

This is the code that matters:

```
delim = ','
    while(getline(&buf, &bufcap, stdin) > 0) {
        int i;
        for(i=0; i < strlen(buf2); i++) {
            if(buf[i] == delim) {
                buf[i] = '\0';
            }
        }

        printf(buf);
```

yields:

```
4050
```

What I want:

```
40\030\020\010
50\060\070\080
```

Comment: the two characters \ and 0 are not the same thing as null character. Printf cannot print null characters. Just putchar characters if not , and `printf("\\0")` when you meet the delimiter

Comment: What is `buf2` and why is its length being used in a loop?

Answer (score 0):

'\0' is a null character, all string functions will stop when reaching that character as it signifies the end of the string

Answer (score 0):

`'\0'` marks the end of a string, so `strlen` will return when it first the reaches one. Therefor, your loop will stop after the first delimeter. The backslash in a character literal always marks an escape code. Combined with the next character, it is used for special characters. You can enter a literal backslash using `'\\'` So you would have to insert two characters: `'\\'` and `'0'`.